# Angularjs NgRoute's controller doesn't work in index.html ng-view

Tags: angularjs, frontend, mean-stack, router, ngroute

MY files are in here https://files.fm/u/va89pjm7#_

The code is very very simple. Why can't I have call {{mail.msg}} in localhost:8080/mail even though I routed "/mail" as mail.html?

Thx to stackoverflow for wonderful community.

Here is the code below:

**server.js**

```
// get the things we need
    var express = require('express'),
        app     = express(),
        path = require('path');

    app.use(express.static('./')); // default index.html
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.3",
    "express": "~4.10.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^1.2.0",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.19",
    "morgan": "~1.5.0"
  }
}
```

**ngapp.js**

```
angular.module("firstApp", ['ngRouter'])
.controller("mainController", function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.msg = "Hello from mainController controller";

})


.controller('mailController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.msg = "Hello from mailController controller";
});
```

**ng_route.js**

```
angular.module('ngRouter', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/mail', {
                    templateUrl: "mail.html",
                    controller: "mailController",
                    controllerAs: "mail"
                });


            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
```

**mail.html**

```
<h3>Hello {{mail.msg}}</h3>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="ngapp.js"></script>
        <script src="ng_route.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="firstApp">
        <section ng-controller="mainController as main">
            <p>{{main.msg}}</p>
        </section>

        <main>
            <div ng-view></div>
             <ng-view></ng-view>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

RESULTS:
localhost:8080/mail   =  Hello from mainController controller
localhost:8080        =  Hello from mainController controller

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question

Comment: @SimonH didn't u see the link?

Comment: Why am I getting -1 point for? I didn't do anything wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which I sometimes found necessary.

```
angular.module("firstApp", ['ngRouter']);
.controller("mainController", function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.msg = "Hello from mainController controller";
    return vm;
})
```

and you need one or the other of thrse lines, but not both

```
        <div ng-view></div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
```

Comment: Try making q plnkr showing it not working and I can look at that

Comment: Can't save it in plunker.. Saved failed =[